# how to access values of nested dictionary keys in python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have nested dictionaries, and I want to update the values of second dictionaries' keys' value such that it should reflect the dictionary value also.

```
class Screen_Seat:
   def __init__(self,screen,show,num_seats,day):
      self.screen_id = screen
      self.show = show
      self.num_seats = num_seats

     self.seats = {('screen1','day4'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
                   ('screen1','day5'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
                   ('screen1','day6'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
                   ('screen1','day7'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},}
```

I would like to update the value of the below keys

```
self.seats['screen1','day4','show4'] =90
```

so that:

```
self.seats = {('screen1','day4'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':**90**},
                       ('screen1','day5'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
                       ('screen1','day6'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
                       ('screen1','day7'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},}
```

how can I do this in python?

**Edit:**

```
class Screen_Seat:
   def __init__(self,screen,show,num_seats,day):
      self.screen_id = screen
      self.show = show
      self.num_seats = num_seats

      self.seats = {('screen1','day4'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
      ('screen1','day5'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
      ('screen1','day6'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
      ('screen1','day7'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
          ('screen2','day1'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
      ('screen2','day2'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
      ('screen2','day3'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
                     }

class Screen_Booking(screen_seat):
   def __init__(self,screen,show,num_seats,day):
       screen_seat.__init__(self,screen,show,num_seats,day)
       self.booking_screen = screen
       self.booking_show = show
       self.booking_day=day
       self.booking_seats=num_seats

   def CheckAvailability(self):
       self.seats[self.booking_screen,self.booking_day][self.booking_show]
       if (self.seats[self.booking_screen,self.booking_day][self.booking_show] > int(self.booking_seats)):
          self.seats[self.booking_screen,self.booking_day][self.booking_show]=(self.seats[self.booking_screen,self.booking_day][self.booking_show]-int(self.booking_seats))

          #print self.seats[self.booking_screen,self.booking_day][self.booking_show]
          print 'seat booked'
       else:
           print 'Sorry, No seats available in Screen1. Please try other Screens'


A1 = Screen_Booking('screen1','show1','98','day4')
A1.CheckAvailability()
A1 = Screen_Booking('screen1','show1','10','day4')
```

output:

```
2
seat booked
90
seat booked
```

Second time it should print 'Sorry, No seats available in Screen1. Please try other Screens'

Help me identify the issue in my code?

Comment: ``self.seats[('screen1', 'day4')]['show4'] = 90``

Comment: new values are not getting updated in class values.

Comment: There is no `screen7` in your code above.

Comment: Also, follow CapWords notation to name your classes. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: @RahulGupta updated classes.

Comment: This is happening because you are creating a new instance of `A1` so all the previous values are lost. You can instead try the solution i posted and it should work.

Comment: @RahulGupta Yeah, It's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
self.seats[('screen1', 'day4')]['show4'] = 90
```

**Output:**

```
self.seats
{('screen1', 'day4'): {'show1': 100, 'show2': 100, 'show3': 100, 'show4': 90},
 ('screen1', 'day5'): {'show1': 100, 'show2': 100, 'show3': 100, 'show4': 100},
 ('screen1', 'day6'): {'show1': 100, 'show2': 100, 'show3': 100, 'show4': 100},
 ('screen1', 'day7'): {'show1': 100, 'show2': 100, 'show3': 100, 'show4': 100}}
```

First access the screen1 day4 shows by `('screen1', 'day4')` tuple as the key in `self.seats` dictionary. Then access the `'show4'` key of the inner dictionary by `'show4'` and set its value to 90.

It seems you are new to python. Let us try to understand the thought process by the following 3 steps.

**Step1:**

`('screen1', 'day4')` gives access to `{'show1': 100, 'show2': 100, 'show3': 100, 'show4': 100}` inner dictionary.

```
self.seats[('screen1', 'day4')]
{'show1': 100, 'show2': 100, 'show3': 100, 'show4': 100}
```

**Step2:**

Now access `show4` by `'show4'` key in the obtained dictionary from the previous step.

```
self.seats[('screen1', 'day4')]['show4']
100
```

**Step3:**

Update the value obtained for screen1-day4-show4 to 90.

```
self.seats[('screen1', 'day4')]['show4'] = 90

self.seats[('screen1', 'day4')]['show4']
90
```

**Code Solution:**

Check this approach if it works for you.

```
class ScreenBooking(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ScreenBooking, self).__init__()
        self.seats = {
            ('screen1','day4'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
            ('screen1','day5'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
            ('screen1','day6'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
            ('screen1','day7'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
            ('screen2','day1'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
            ('screen2','day2'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
            ('screen2','day3'):{'show1':100,'show2':100,'show3':100,'show4':100},
        }
        self.shows = ['show1', 'show2', 'show3', 'show4']


    def check_valid_details(self, screen, show, day):
        """
        Check if booking details are valid and return True/False accordingly.
        """
        if (screen, day) not in self.seats or show not in self.shows:
            return  False
        return True

    def book_seats(self, screen, show, no_of_seats, day):
        """
        Book seats after checking valid booking details and the remaining seats.
        """
        valid_details = self.check_valid_details(screen, show, day)
        if not valid_details:
            print 'Invalid booking details!'
            return
        show_total_seats = self.seats[(screen, day)][show]
        if show_total_seats > int(no_of_seats):
            show_remaining_seats = show_total_seats - int(no_of_seats)
            self.seats[(screen, day)][show] = show_remaining_seats #update the seats count
            print '%s seat(s) booked'%(no_of_seats)
        else:
            print 'Sorry, No seats available in %s. Please try other Screens'%(screen)

a1 = ScreenBooking()
a1.book_seats('screen1','show1','98','day4')
a1.book_seats('screen1','show1','10','day4')
```

Comment: You are getting this outpput because you are again creating a new instance of `screen_booking` with `seats` values as defined in `screen_seat` class.

Comment: Hey Lucifier! I have coded a solution for your problem. Check out if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary has two nested levels, one indexed with a `('screenX', 'dayX')` tuple, the other with a `showX` string. Observe the following:

```
>>> foo.seats['screen1', 'day4']
{'show4': 90, 'show2': 100, 'show1': 100, 'show3': 100}
>>> foo.seats['screen1', 'day4']['show4']
90
```

The first expression gives you a dictionary that you have to index again in order to get the desired element. So the final expression is:

```
foo.seats['screen1', 'day4']['show4']
#         ^                  ^
#         |                  |
#         +-- First level    +-- Second level
```